# VBS script to detect idle time like a screensaver

Tags: vbscript, screensaver

I want to know how to make an idle time counter in vbs, like a screensaver so when the idle time exeeds lets say 10 mins, it launches my screensaver and resets it to 0. When the mouse is moved, I also want it to end the screensaver, which I think is possible when it ends the procces in task manager named cmd.exe (the screensaver runs in cmd) here is what I have done so far, and thank you in advance

```
Const strComputer = "." 
Dim objWMIService, colProcessList
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Dim StartTime, EndTime, Elapsed

StartTime = Timer

Elapsed = Timer - StartTime

for each Process in Service.InstancesOf ("Win32_Process")

If Timer > 1000 Then
If Process.Name = "cmd.exe" then
sleep 0
else
createObject("WScript.Shell").Run "screensaver.bat"
if (mouse move)                                                *NOT DONE*
   Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'cmd.exe'")
  For Each objProcess in colProcessList 
    objProcess.Terminate() 

StartTime = 0
EndTime = 0
Elapsed = 0
Timer = 0
end if
next


   Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'Process.exe'")
  For Each objProcess in colProcessList 
    objProcess.Terminate() 

  Next
```

Comment: You just described how the Windows screensaver works. Why would you want to replicate the behavior instead of using what's already there?

Comment: that is becuase I want to use my own and the screensaver setter wont let me so i want to make a launcher in VBS

Comment: The only advice I have for that is: don't.